# RF Matching Net

Tags: power-supply, rf, noise, impedance, impedance-matching

I am projecting a system that contains two RF chips, a LoRa SX1276 (915MHz) chip and a ESP32-D0WDQ6 (2.5GHz).

1. In the schematic bellow, the ESP32 (2.4GHz) design has a matching net between the chip and the antena:

[image]

The LNA_IN pin has a impedance of 30+j10 Ω for this package, and the antenna has a impedance of 50 Ω. Solving the system, the antenna "sees" a 10.9722 - 6.0798i Ω impedance, instead of a 50 Ω, so it is not matching. This net is used in some commercial products. Is not it leading the wave to reflect and then come into the chip, losing power? If so, how to match properly and what to consider?

2. The LoRa chip bellow as well as the ESP32 have some GPIOs and some digital pins:

[image]

The power tree contains 2 LDOs: One LDO (ultra high PSRR) powers the analog pins of both chips; The other
LDO powers the digital line of both chips. Is this configuration recommended? This was planned to avoid digital pins to disturb analog power signal to the RF system.

3. In case it is ok with that said in the second item, above, is it needed to split the ground plane into two (digital and analog) for each IC?
4. Considering the external power supply being a step-down working in the 400kHz switching frequency, with a ripple of around 50mV, the graphs bellow show the PSRR of the LDO used to power the analog line of both chips.

[image]

Following the formula:

[image]

Then the ripple at the output of the LDO is expected to be around 0.15mV (considering that on 400kHz the PSRR of the LDO is ~50). So, is that clean enough to power both RF chips so that they work properly?

Regards,
Emanuel

Comment: Looks reasonable , but graphs are nominal not worst  case

Comment: What exactly you say it is reasonable? In which topic (1 to 4)? Could you complement your answer, please?

Comment: I was thinking of LDO but a RLC prefilter should be considered...  the RF filters look odd to me, what specs?

Comment: I think to get a clean power supply based on the RF LDO, the PSRR needs to be very high at the switching frequency of the switching regulator that supplies the LDO.

Comment: I was just playing around with some ideas here for filters  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHqGi.png

Comment: Hm, I think I would need a low pass filter, with ferrite beads on the input of the LDOs, to make sure no high frequency signal is going to dirt the power signals.

Comment: I would suggest duplicating the layout, and the matching parts used in the manufacturer’s eval boards/application notes for the chip antenna interface.  They have likely fooled with it enough to know what works.  You will not be able to do better.

Answer (score 2):

If your central power is a Switching Regulator, then the 1MHz and 10MHz and 100MHz switcher ringing will come on thru the LDOs.

Expect to place L+C prefilters before each LDO.

Comment: Which cut freq. do you suggest to set for the LC filter before each LDO?

Comment: Could you please answer the other questions, if it is possible. I am a little bit lost, so that 1 to 4 asks could possibly solve my doubt! Thanks for your patience!